# How to make two elements get half space in single row

Tags: html, css

I try to make two elements `input` type text and `input` type button in a single line and each element get half of the space.

Here is how I try to achieve it:

```css
#myCard{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin; 
  padding: 12px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.halfWidth{
  position: relative;;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="myCard">
<input type="text" class="halfWidth" value="click">
<input type="button" class="halfWidth" value="click" onclick="foo()">
</div>
```

But as you can see my code not works

Comment: One thing right away, in your CSS, change `#myCard` to `.myCard` as its a class selector and not and id

Answer (score 1):

Using `display: flex;` on the container will allow both child elements to shrink a bit and fit them in to one line. (and use *either* class *or* ID on the container...)

```css
.myCard{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin; 
  padding: 12px 5px 5px 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.halfWidth{
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="myCard">
<input type="text" class="halfWidth" value="click">
<input type="button" class="halfWidth" value="click" onclick="foo()">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add display:flex to #myCard and as Tanner mentioned above change to .myCard

```
.myCard{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin; 
  padding: 12px 5px 5px 5px;
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are using class on html and call the id on the css, beside that you are not giving a width to the father myCard. And the names are wrong.

Try this:

```css
.myCard{
  width:100%; 
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin; 
  padding: 12px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.halfWidth{
  position: relative;;
  width:49%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="myCard">
<input type="text" class="halfWidth" value="click">
<input type="button" class="halfWidth" value="click" onclick="foo()">
</div>
```

Comment: If you correct your typo ("halffWidth"/"halfWidth"), the result is the same as in the question...

Comment: No is not, 50% it's not exact using display:inline-block, you can use float:left, instead but you will need to declarate position:relative and overflow:hidden to the father, and then 50% will work. Check de code snippet and they look equal width and one next to each other. display:flex and flex:2 works great too